# Using `cp` within `find` while preserving directory structure (bash)

Tags: bash, find, cp

This is a specific question about using `cp` within `find` while preserving directory structure. This is the way that seems like it should work, but perhaps there is a way to do it better. The reason I am using `find` is because I only want to copy files of a certain age.

I have a directory structure like this. The operating system is Ubuntu 16.04.

```
folders
   folder1
     file1.txt
   folder2
     file1.txt
     file2.txt
   folder3
     file1.txt
```

I am using the `cp` command within the `find` command, as so...

```
find "$pathtofolder"/* -mmin +"$timeinmins" -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp --parents {} /var/www/website/archives \;
```

The `--parents` flag copies the entire path to the files so I get something like `archives/var/www/website/folders/folder1/file1.txt`. This is not what I'm going for. I just want `archives/folder1/file1.txt`.

The `-R` and `-a` flags do not work in this statement within `find`. When I use either one of them they seem to stop the copy from happening at all.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: @tripleee Not exactly a duplicate because OP found out the `--parents` option of `cp`. His problem is actually to get rid of the first path level when copying the file.

Comment: There are multiple answers there which solve this particular aspect, including `rsync` and `tar`.

Comment: The answers I have found, including the one you mention, are just a simple copy. I only want to copy certain files. As I do not have much bash experience, you may be right that I just need to do a simple copy of the whole directory then do a selective `rm` in `find` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following variables:

```
pathtofolder="/tmp/test" 
pathtoarchive="/var/www/website/archives"
```

You could use this:

```
 find "$pathtofolder" -type f -mmin +"$timeinmins" -exec bash -c 'dir="$2/$(sed "s,^$3,,;s,/[^/]\+$,," <<< "$1")"; mkdir -p "$dir"; cp -v "$1" "$dir"' _ {} "$pathtoarchive" "${pathtofolder}/folders/" \;
```

`sed` is used to make the the target directory and assign it to the variable `dir`. The command removes the first level directory and the name from the filename found by `find`.

`mkdir -p` will create the target directory and will not complain if the directory already exist.

Once the directory is created, the copy is done.

Comment: Thanks very much. The code is more complicated than I was expecting. Would the number of directories make a difference to the code? E.g. `pathtofolder=/var/www/website/laravel/folder` and `pathtoarchive=/var/www/website/laravel/archives`.

Comment: Am I using the right approach? Would it be simpler to split it into two to find the older files first then I think I could just use a `cp -a`, or I could do the copy in a simpler way.

Comment: @sdexp It shouldn't make any difference, but since your source and target directories share the same path, it might be easier to `/var/www/website/laravel` and do the `find` command from there.

Comment: @sdexp Another approach is to use `rsync`

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I am still getting `archives/var/www` when I try your method and I'm very far from being able to debug. It might be a lot easier to use `rsync`, like you say, and just copy all files over. Then only delete the files that are too old.